# Aggregate rows per its text pattern using Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, text-mining

I am working on an interesting text mining (maybe text pattern recognition) problem. The dataset has two columns as follows:

```
column1 (string)            column2 (integer)
'ABC'                             3
'DEF'                             4
'abc'                             1
'abc:very specific message'       1
...
```

The first column is input message, while the second one is its count. For many of the input messages, they are in fact the same, but different with regard to the details, e.g., the third row and the fourth row deliver the same message, but the fourth row has more specific information compared to the third one.

How can I create an algorithm to aggregate those rows with high similarity? By the end of the day, the aggregate data will be somehow as follows:

```
column1 (string)            column2 (integer)
'ABC'                             3
'DEF'                             4
'abc'                             2
```

Comment: You could split the string by `:` and pick the first element of that split, then group by the result. Is that what you're looking for? Can you explain in more detail why `abc` and `abc:very specific message` are similar? You might also look into [LCS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_common_subsequence)

Comment: Thank you for your input @NickODell. "abc" and "abc: very specific message" can be as following.
abc: "I had a breakfast"
abc: very specific: "I had a breakfast: it is two eggs"
I only want to extract the key information "I had a breakfast", and aggregate those rows together. 
In addition there could be several `:` before the specific details is delivered, e.g., 
`abc`: "Yesterday:I had a breakfast:with my boyfriend"
`abc: very specific': "Yesterday:I had a breakfast:with my boyfriend:it is coffee and bagel". 
My current thought is this problem is related to similarity search. Thanks.

Comment: Not sure this blog helps us: https://newscatcherapi.com/blog/ultimate-guide-to-text-similarity-with-python

Comment: I think I am in the right direction. Please check below as a simple implementation:

`from difflib import SequenceMatcher
def similar(a, b):
    return SequenceMatcher(None, a, b).ratio()
text1 = "Yesterday:I had a breakfast:with my boyfriend"
text2 = "Yesterday:I had a breakfast:with my boyfriend:it is coffee and bagel"
similar(text1, text2)'

The output is: 0.80 (rounded)
I think I can use the similarity ratio to justify whether any two rows has high enough similarity. Thanks for discussion.

Answer (score 1):

I think I am in the right direction. Please check below as a simple implementation:

```
from difflib import SequenceMatcher
def similar(a, b):
    return SequenceMatcher(None, a, b).ratio()
text1 = "Yesterday:I had a breakfast:with my boyfriend"
text2 = "Yesterday:I had a breakfast:with my boyfriend:it is coffee and bagel"
similar(text1, text2)
```

The output is: 0.80 (rounded)

We can use the similarity ratio to justify whether any two rows has high enough similarity. Thanks for discussion.